# Ctest does not find catch2 tests with subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I don't seem to get my CTest project to recognize my Catch2 tests. The test project itself builds fine and I manage to run the tests using the executable created by it. However when running

```
ctest -V
```

The output I keep getting is:

```
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/user/code/project/libs/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/user/code/project/libs/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /home/user/code/project/libs/
Constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
No tests were found!!!
```

My set-up is as follows:

The folder structure:

```
libs
├── maths
│   ├── matrix.cpp / hpp
│   ├── function.cpp / hpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── ctest
│   ├── matrix_test.cpp
│   ├── function_test.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
```

└── CMakeLists.txt

I build from the build folder

```
cmake ..
cmake --build .
ctest -V
```

CMakeLists.txt in ctest

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp
    maths/matrix_test.cpp
    maths/function_test.cpp
)

# find the Catch2 library 
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

# create a test executable
add_executable(ctest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ctest maths Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(ParseAndAddCatchTests)
ParseAndAddCatchTests(ctest)
```

The main CMakeLists.txt

```
# set CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(mathlib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "lib")

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

set(LIB_BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs")

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory("${LIB_BASE_DIR}/maths" maths)
add_subdirectory("${LIB_BASE_DIR}/ctest" ctest)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(ctest)

add_test(
    NAME catch_test
    COMMAND $<TARGET-FILE>:ctest --success
)
```

I have looked at the recipes here, the cmake cookbook, modern-cmake, the catch2 github page, but I seem to miss something obvious as for some reason the tests do not get picked up. I have not been able to find an example with add_subdirectory so may be that leads to a different set-up.

If I run

```
./bin/ctest
```

all tests run fine. So the executable itself is fine.

Comment: Where did you define the target `var_ctest` that you pass to `catch_discover_tests()`? Also, I think all of the test related code can got into CMakeLists.txt in ctest.

Comment: Have you tried renaming your testdirectory and testbinary. Maybe ctest is confused by a binaryfile called ctest.